# PHP Curl to send SMS

Tags: php, api, curl, while-loop, sms

I am pretty much at the beginner's level for PHP and cURL.
The issue is related to a **php CronJob Script** which fetches data from a phpmyadmin database relating to customer orders with a particular status (say "0", which means SMS not sent/or No Update Sent to Customer) and updating the shipping details.

*Before adding the code to send SMS via API from my SMS Service Provider, the script was working fine which was being used to send emails, regarding shipping updates and following that, updating the database like Order Status and other necessary details to the customer as well as in the system.*

> The issue arises that if, suppose 100-150 results are fetched as
>   arrays with status='0' the loop only executes once and stops, whereas
>   before adding the SMS code, it used to run for **n** number rows
>   fetched with status='0'.

I've tried almost all the methods listed on **StackOverflow, PHP Manuals, W3C** as well as from the developer but still I'm unable to make it work successfully for all the results fetched.

Things I wan't -
 **1. Select data from a table where status='0'. **✓**
 2. Get details relating to the order using mysqli_fetch_array.**✓**
 3. Send Email as per the format in the code.**✓**
 4. Update Order History and Order Status.**✓**
 5. Send an SMS using API as per the prescribed template. (⍻ Not Working)**

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","pass","database");//database connection
$get_email_contents = "SELECT * FROM `oc_shipping` WHERE `status`='0'";
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$date = date('Y-m-d');
if($data = mysqli_query($con,$get_email_contents))
{
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{

$order_id = $row['order_id'];
$tracking_no = $row['tracking_awb'];


$get_email = "SELECT * FROM `oc_order` WHERE `order_id`='$order_id'";
if($email_data = mysqli_query($con,$get_email))
{
while ($email_row=mysqli_fetch_array($email_data))
{
$email = str_replace(" ","",$email_row['email']);
$firstname = ucwords($email_row['firstname']);
$lastname = ucwords($email_row['lastname']);
$received_on = $email_row['date_added'];
$date_added = date("d M Y",strtotime($received_on));
$address_1 = $email_row['shipping_address_1'];
$address_2 = $email_row['shipping_address_2'];
$city = $email_row['shipping_city'];
$pincode = $email_row['shipping_postcode'];
$total = str_replace(".0000","",$email_row['total']);
$mobile = $email_row['telephone'];

$delivery_date = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($date. ' + 7 days'));
$track_url = "https://track.delhivery.com/p/".$tracking_no;
$text = "ABC.com
Hi ".$firstname.", Your Order ".$order_id." has been shipped via XYZ AWB #".$tracking_no.", which can be tracked on ".$track_url."
Expected delivery date is ".$delivery_date.". Please keep ready Rs.".$total."/- on the date of delivery.
Thank you for shopping on ABC.com";
echo "SMS Sent : ".$text."<br><br>";
$encode= rawurlencode($text);

//Just for my reference
$url= "login.smshub.com/api/mt/SendSMS?APIKey=****&senderid=ABCABC&channel=2&DCS=0&Route=1&Flashsms=0&Number=$mobile&Text=$encode";


$ch = curl_init("login.smshub.com/api/mt/SendSMS?APIKey=****&senderid=ABCABC&channel=2&DCS=0&Route=1&Flashsms=0&Number=$mobile&Text=$encode");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($data);
$JobID = $json->{'JobId'};
$Error = $json->{'ErrorMessage'};

echo "Status : <strong>$JobID $Error </strong><br>";  

//Email Receiver//
   $to = "$email";

   //From Header//
   $header = "From: ABC.com<shipping@example.com>"."\r\n";
   $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" . "\r\n";

   // Subject //
   $subject = "Your Order #$order_id has been Shipped";

   // Message //
   $message = "<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
<table align='center' cellpadding='1' style='background-color:#ffffff; border-color:#f3f3f3; border-radius:10px; border-size:1px; border-style:outset; max-width: 100%; width:100%; font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; '>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center'>
            <p style='text-align:center'><a href='example.com' target='_blank'><img alt='abc.com' height='63' src='example.com/image/shipping/Logo.gif' width='250' /></a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style='border-color:#f3f3f3; text-align:center; white-space:nowrap; width:50%'>
            <p>Thank you for shopping on abc</p>

            <h3 style='text-align:left;margin-left: 40px;'>Order Details</h3>

            <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='5' style='background-color:#f2f2f2; border-radius:5px; color:#333333; width:85%;'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p style='text-align:left'>Order Number: <strong>$order_id</strong></p>

                        <p style='text-align:left'>Date Received: <strong>$date_added</strong></p>

                        <p style='text-align:left'>Name: <strong>$firstname $lastname</strong></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' style='border-color:#f3f3f3; text-align:center'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' style='border-color:#f3f3f3; text-align:center'>
            <h3 style='text-align:left;margin-left: 40px;'>Delivery Address</h3>

            <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='5' style='background-color:#f2f2f2; border-radius:5px; color:#333333; padding:7px; width:85%;'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p style='text-align:left'><strong>$address_1</strong></p>

                        <p style='text-align:left'><strong>$address_2</strong></p>

                        <p style='text-align:left'><strong>$city - $pincode</strong></p>

                        <p style='text-align:left'><strong>Mobile No. $mobile</strong></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center'>
            <p style='text-align:center'><img alt='Order Shipped' height='90' src='example.com/image/shipping/Shipping.jpg' width='410' /></p>

            <p>Your order has been shipped from our warehouse.</p>

            <p>Amount Payable</p>

            <h2>Rs.<strong>$total</strong></h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center;'>
            <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' style='background-color:#000000; border-radius:5px; color:#ffffff; font-size:larger; font-weight:700; padding:10px 15px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; width:85%;'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href='https://track.xyz.com/p/$tracking_no' target='_blank' style='padding:15px 25px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;'>TRACK PACKAGE</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center'>
            <p><br />
            &nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
            <p style='text-align:center'><em><span style='font-size:12px'>Instructions</span></em></p>

            <table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='5' style='background-color:#f2f2f2; border-radius:5px; color:#333333; width:85%;'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span style='font-size:12px'>1.Please do not accept the package, if it is damaged / tampered before delivery.</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span style='font-size:12px'>2.Your freebies (if any) shall be inside the package.</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span style='font-size:12px'>3.Please mention remarks while signing for delivery, if you doubt that the package might be damaged or is suspicious.</span></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center'>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            <p><span style='font-size:12px; color:#a9a9a9;'>Note: We do not demand your bank or credit card details over phone. Please do not divulge these details to fraudsters claiming to be calling on behalf of abc.&nbsp;</span></p>

            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' style='text-align:center'>
            <p>Contact Us</p>

            <p><strong><a href='mailto:help@abc.com?subject=Regarding%20Order%20ID%20$order_id' style='text-decoration:none; color:#000;'>help@example.com</a></strong></p>

            <p><span style='font-size:10px; color:#a9a9a9;'>Do not reply to this email, this is an automated email sent to $email.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html> \r\n";


   //Send Mail//
   $mail_send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

   if($mail_send)
   {

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","admin","pass","database");//database connection
   $delete = "UPDATE `oc_ship` SET `status`='1' WHERE `order_id`='$order_id'";
   if($deleted = mysqli_query($con,$delete))
   {
   $update_comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,"<p>Your order has been shipped via XYZ AWB #<b>$tracking_no</b>.</p> <p><a href='track.xyz.com/p/$tracking_no' target='_blank'>Click here to track your order</a></p>");
  $date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $order_history = "INSERT INTO `oc_order_hist`(`order_id`,`order_status_id`,`notify`,`comment`,`date_added`) VALUES ('$order_id','3','1','$update_comment','$date_time')";
   if($order_history_update = mysqli_query($con,$order_history))
   {
  $order_status = "UPDATE `oc_order` SET `order_status_id`='3' WHERE `order_id`='$order_id'";

    if($order_status_update = mysqli_query($con,$order_status))
    { 

   echo "<br><strong>Shipping Updated successfully for Order ID $order_id</strong><br>";

   }
   }

   }
}
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: The SMS Service Provider has also given options using XML to send SMS.

Comment: Your code is quite hard to read without proper spacing and indentation, so I'm not going to try reading it all, but is there perhaps an error being thrown inside the loop? This could explain why it stops on the first iteration. You said that it worked fine until you added the SMS code - is there a misnamed DB column perhaps?

Comment: Also, you're not checking for cURL errors - there could be a network problem.

Comment: try using `try-catch` around the sms code and dump error on exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the script worked as expected until you added the SMS-sending code, that would imply that there's a problem with the new code.

Extract the SMS-sending code into a file on its own and test that, perhaps from the command line. Don't forget to check for cURL-specific errors (network errors, SSL error, etc.) with [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and [`curl_errno()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php), like this:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) > 0) {
    print 'There was a cURL error: ' . $curl_error($ch);
}
```

Check the PHP and server logs also for error messages.

Comment: How should I check curl errors here ?

This was the code I had put in a separate file , sms.php and then I used include(); function

SMS Sending Code starts from $delivery_date and ends at echo "Success";....

Comment: What I meant was to run that block of code by itself, perhaps from the command line: `php sms.php` - the idea is to isolate it from everything else so that you can more easily see what's going wrong. I'll update my answer to show you the use of the cURL error functions.

Comment: It still stops after 1 loop

Comment: You never said what error message you're getting - either at the console or in the logs. Also, test ONLY the SMS-sending code on its own - take it out of the loop and try it by itself. Run it from the command line so you can see any error messages returned, and check the PHP log too. Beyond that, you're providing very little information, and your code is too hard to read, so it's difficult to help you - I'm only guessing.

Comment: How to log error ?
I am not able to understand that,I've tried many forums to see how error logging is done for particular file. The code has been run separately but it loops just 1 time.